# Case statement in shell script

Tags: bash, case

I have the following problem.
How can I loop trough a .csv file and do an something when the ID of $d is a certain number.
I made one with an if elseif like this that works fine:

```
while read a b c d e
do
if [ "$d" = "20.000" ]
    then 
        ACTION
elif [ "$d" = "24.000" ]
    then
        ACTION
elif [ "$d" = "28.000" ]
    then
        ACTION
elif [ "$d" = "32.000" ]
    then
        ACTION
elif [ "$d" = "53.000" ]
    then
        ACTION
elif [ "$d" = "8.000" ]
    then
        ACTION
elif [ "$d" = "36.000" ]
    then
        ACTION
elif [ "$d" = "37.000" ]
    then
        ACTION
```

Now this code becomes very long and was looking for a nicer solution.
I have the following, but I get the following errors.

> line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `of' line 24:`     case $d of'

Here is my code:

```
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read a b c d e
#a=name
#b=northing
#c=easting
#d=id
#e=color
do
read d
case $d of
    exit) break ;;
    20.000) echo "NBUOY" ;;
    24.000) echo "EBUOY" ;;
    28.000) echo "SBUOY" ;;
    32.000) echo "WBUOY" ;;
    53.000) echo "RBUOY" ;;
    8.000) echo "RBUOY" ;;
    36.000) echo "RBUOY" ;;
    37.000) echo "RBUOY" ;;
    55.000) echo "RBUOY" ;;
    10.000) echo "RBUOY" ;;
    14.000) echo "GBUOY" ;;
    16.000) echo "GBUOY" ;;
    6.000) echo "YSBUOY" ;;
    4.000) echo "YSBUOY" ;;
    1.000) echo "YSBUOY" ;;
    5.000) echo "YSBUOY" ;;
    *) echo "Unknown response, enter a number 1-12 or type 'exit' to quit" ;;
esac
```

done

What is going wrong? and is this even possible?

Comment: Should be "case $d in" and not "case $d of"

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)'s message is more explicit: it points to the `of` and says `Expected 'in'.`